# modalDialog doesn`t appear if sankeyNetwork (networkD3) is used

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, sankey-diagram, networkd3

I have a problem when I use modalDialog in shiny and sankeyNetwork (networkD3). If the sankeyNetwork is rendered in the app then modalDialog doesn`t appear - I can see only grey screen but without dialog window.

[Click Show Modal when sankeyNetwor is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgSkj.png)

[Click Show Modal when sankeyNetwork is not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRX4d.png)

Example of app to show described problem below.

```
library(shiny)
library(networkD3)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$show_modal,{
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = NULL, size = "m",
      h4("Test Window"),
      footer = NULL, easyClose = T
    ))
  })

  output$sankey <- renderSankeyNetwork({
    nodes<-data.frame(
      name=paste0(rep("opt",9),seq(1,9)), stringsAsFactors = F)

    links<-data.frame(
      source=c(0,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6),
      target=c(4,5,6,5,6,4,6,6,7,8,7,8),
      value=c(2,3,5,1,2,3,1,6,1,3,7,4))

    quest<-list(nodes=nodes, links=links)
    sankeyNetwork(Links = quest$links, Nodes = quest$nodes, Source = "source",
                  Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                  units = "opt", fontSize = 16, nodeWidth = 30, iterations = 2, sinksRight = T)
  })

  output$show_sankey<-renderUI({
    if(input$show_sankeyNetwork_box) sankeyNetworkOutput('sankey')
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Modaldialog + sankeyNetwork (networkD3) Problem"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    actionButton("show_modal", "Show modal"),
                    checkboxInput('show_sankeyNetwork_box', "Show sankeyNetwork", value = F)),
                  mainPanel(
                    uiOutput('show_sankey'))
                ))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Do you know how to deal with this issue ?

Thanks !

Bartek

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shiny App-showModal does not pop up with renderSankeyNetwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46252133/shiny-app-showmodal-does-not-pop-up-with-rendersankeynetwork)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. It`s exactly this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved with the dev version of `shiny` and should be released on CRAN soon as `shiny v1.3.3`.